# How does the application of Schrödinger equation to model a particle in a box explain the origin of degeneracy of atomic orbitals?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

Is the particle in a box concept analogous to an electron in an orbital? If so, can we apply the equation for the allowed energies of a particle in a box

$$E = \frac{h^2n^2}{8mL^2}$$

to the allowed energies of electrons in orbitals? Are the orbitals degenerate because this equation only includes the quantum number $n$ and not the others and therefore all orbitals in a subshell will *roughly* be degenerate?

Finally, if this equation can be used to explain the allowed energies of orbitals/electrons, what would $L$ be in this instance?

Comment: No, that would be too much of a stretch.

Comment: 1D or 2D box? 1D has no degeneracy

Comment: Electrons in orbitals do not have spatial constrains like particles in a box. There is no sharp cut off of probability density. Particular borders of orbital 3D shapes are just arbitrary convention of probability density threshold and the residual integral probability threshold.

Comment: I was referring to 1D. Ok understood. So how would you guys go about answering the question?

Comment: I have to ask, what is the source of this question? Curiosity or homework or ...?

Comment: This question is on an assignment I was given for university level chemistry. "How does the application of the Schrodinger equation to model system such as particle in a box help us understand the origin of the degeneracy of atomic orbitals". I have been racking my brain all week and can't get it.

Comment: My answer to another post tries to explain a link between the problems: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149738/schr%c3%b6dinger-equation-and-degeneracy-of-atomic-orbitals/149741#149741 This seems unlikely to be a good question for intro chem though. That's why I asked why you were posting this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the particle in a box concept analogous to an electron in an orbital?

No, but there is an analogy to the $\pi$ systems of dye molecules, and (for the 3D box) to the band structure of nanodots. Some physical chemistry courses have a lab that explore this relationship, e.g. at [Saarland university](https://www.uni-saarland.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Professoren/fr81_ProfHempelmann/Harald/Anleitung_Spektroskopie_01_TIK.pdf) (sorry, in German, but the figures and the math are universally understandable, I hope).

> Finally, if this equation can be used to explain the allowed energies of orbitals/electrons, what would L be in this instance?

It would be the length of the conjugated system (for the dyes) or the radius (for the nanoparticles)

> Are the orbitals degenerate because this equation only includes the quantum number n and not the others and therefore all orbitals in a subshell will roughly be degenerate?

For a 1D case with degeneracy, you can explore the particle in a ring, [Why do solutions of electron in a box (and in a ring) predict coefficients for LCAO (linear combination of atomic orbitals) in 1D systems?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/116840/72973).