# Schrödinger equation and degeneracy of atomic orbitals

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

How does the application of the [Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation) to model a system, such as a particle in a box, help us understand the origin of the degeneracy of atomic orbitals?

Comment: It doesn't. Unless we apply it to a model system which is a hydrogen atom, that is.

Comment: I would argue it does if you consdier a 2D (or 3D etc.) box and consider under what conditions you can get degeneracies. But I also would argue this isn't the world's greatest ever exam question.

Comment: I'd say the simplest model possessing degeneracy is the particle on a ring, which is quasi 1D for fixed radius.

Answer (score 5):

Degeneracy refers to states having the same energy.

If you have two or more coordinates that can be related by a symmetry operation then the system will contain degenerate states because swapping the coordinates associated with those degrees will result in a Hamiltonian with the same solutions.

This is the case in both the hydrogen atom and in the particle in a cube.

Comment: Non accidental Degeneracy implies symmetry but symmetry does not always imply degeneracy. The 1D particle in a box system does have inversion symmetry if you construct it with the center at the origin but it has no degenerate states. A good discussion is found here, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319096/what-is-the-relationship-between-symmetry-and-degeneracy-in-quantum-mechanics

Comment: I know what you mean and your answer is ok. My comment is intended for questionener's/readers that may want are more in depth view at symmetry and degeneracy. It's easy to jump to the wrong conclusion that symmetry always implies degeneracy so i thought it wouldn't hurt to mention it in a comment.

Comment: @HansWurst You're right, and I repost my comment because I was unclear. I meant symmetric coordinates ie rotate x to y. If you have the same Hamiltonian after a symmetry operation that *swaps coordinates* then degeneracy follows. That's all I meant.

Comment: This is not right. Consider the Hamiltoninan $H=-\partial_x^2-\partial_y^2+(x-y)^2$ with Dirichlet boundaries at $x,y=\pm1$. It's invariant with respect to reflection $x\leftrightarrow y$, but the symmetry group is abelian, so you don't get degeneracy (except maybe accidental).

Comment: @Ruslan undoubtedly you are correct. However I don't think referring to Abelian groups will enlighten the OP (or me for that matter, who cannot explain it other than saying abelian group elements commute). Maybe I should add something hand-wavy about particular symmetry conditions that must be satisfied. I am looking for an explanation that is accessible to someone who does not know of group theory.